# Running vssadmin from python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, 32bit-64bit, popen

I'm trying to write a simple script for myself that will delete Windows restore points, I have tried to use the `os` module and then `os.system` but it says `vssadmin is not recognized`, also , I have tried to use `subprocess` and then `communicate` with the `cmd`, but I can't `communicate` twice, I don't know why.

Is there a way to run the following script in Python into cmd ?

It will remove all remove all shadows of system restore points and then ask me if I want to do this.

```
vssadmin delete shadows /all
y
```

**First example:**

It will throw me an error because I'm trying to communicate with the command prompt twice.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate('vssadmin delete shadows /all'.encode())
proc.communicate('y'.encode())
```

**Second Example:**

It will not recognize my code.

```
import os

os.system('vssadmin delete shadows /all')
os.system('y')
```

Comment: Try `command = 'vssadmin delete shadows /all'.split() proc.communicate(command.encode())
`

Comment: @RaihanKabir I can't encode a list.

Comment: If you need to encode you can do it `args =  'vssadmin delete shadows /all'.encode()` and then `command = args.split()`

Comment: @RaihanKabir Non of this working, split is converting my string into a list, and you can't pass a list as argument.

Comment: Opps yes sorry for bad information. I think you should try `p = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe vssadmin delete shadows /all".encode().split()  ...)` and then communicate with `p.communicate('y'.encode())`

Comment: @RaihanKabir Can you please try this instead of throwing me answers that now work.

Comment: Check the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few problems:

1. You are using `communicate` instead of `stdin.write`
2. You are writing `'y'` instead of `'y\n'`
3. You are using `vssadmin` instead of `c:\Windows\Sysnative\vssadmin.exe` (vssadmin is a 32 bit application and you are probably using a 64 bit python)
4. Using `stdin` to communicate will probably not work anyway, just use the flag `/quiet`

The following code might help you achieve better results:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([r'c:\Windows\Sysnative\vssadmin.exe', 'delete', 'shadows', '/all', '/quiet'])
```